# C++: no matching function for call: why is an empty constructor needed?

Tags: c++, c++11, constructor, default-constructor

When I try to compile the following code:

```
class a {

  int i;

  public :
  a(int);
};

class b {
  a mya;  
  int j;

  public:
  b(int);

};

a::a(int i2) {
  i=i2;
}

b::b(int i2) {
  mya=a(i2); 
  j=2*i2;
}

int main() {

}
```

I get the following errors:

```
prog.cpp:21:12: error: no matching function for call to ‘a::a()

 b::b(int i2) {
            ^
prog.cpp:17:1: note: candidate: ‘a::a(int)

 a::a(int i2) {
 ^
prog.cpp:17:1: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
prog.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr a::a(const a&)’
 class a {
       ^
prog.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
prog.cpp:1:7: note: candidate: ‘constexpr a::a(a&&)

prog.cpp:1:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 0 provided
```

It seems that a constructor with no argument for the class a is expected. I do not understand why, the only time I create a object of type a, I call the constructor which takes an int as argument.

I understand that the solution would be to add  a constructor without arguments for a.
But why ?

Thank you for your answers,
best regards,

Jerome

Comment: If you don't explicitly call the constructor - the compiler tries to construct the object with a default constructor: `b::b(int i2) : mya (i2) {`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does a move constructor require a default constructor for its members?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39297334/why-does-a-move-constructor-require-a-default-constructor-for-its-members)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>*(All ISO Standard references below refer to [N4659: March 2017 post-Kona working draft/C++17 DIS](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/))*</sub>

---

As per [[class.base.init]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.base.init#9), the `mya` member of `b`, which is of type `a`, is default-initialized, but `a` defines no default constructor:

> In **a non-delegating constructor, if a given potentially constructed
>   subobject is not designated by a mem-initializer-id** (including the
>   case where **there is no mem-initializer-list** because the constructor
>   has no ctor-initializer), **then**
>
> - (9.1) **if the entity** is a non-static data member that **has a default member initializer** [...] the entity **is initialized from its default member initializer** as specified in [dcl.init];
> - (9.2) otherwise, if the entity is an anonymous union or a variant member ([class.union.anon]), no initialization is performed;
> - (9.3) otherwise, **the entity is default-initialized.**

Here, as `mya` does is not declared along with a default member initializer, [[class.base.init]/9.3](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.base.init#9.3) applies.

The example of [[class.base.init]/9](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.base.init#9) even cover this particular case:

> [...] [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct A {
>   A();
> };
>
> struct B {
>   B(int);
> };
>
> struct C {
>   C() { }               // initializes members as follows:
>   A a;                  // OK: calls A​::​A()
>   const B b;            // error: B has no default constructor
>   int i;                // OK: i has indeterminate value
>   int j = 5;            // OK: j has the value 5
> };
> ```
>
> — end example ]

You can resolve it either by providing a default member initializer for `mya`, such that [[class.base.init]/9.1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.base.init#9.1) applies

```
class b {
  a mya{42};  // default member initializer
  int j;

  public:
  b(int);
};
```

or, use a member initializer list in the definition of the constructor of `b`; `b::b(int)`, such that [[class.base.init]/7](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/class.base.init#7) applies:

> The expression-list or braced-init-list in a mem-initializer is used
>   to initialize the designated subobject (or, in the case of a
>   delegating constructor, the complete class object) according to the
>   initialization rules of [dcl.init] for direct-initialization.
>   [ Example:
>
> ```
> struct B1 { B1(int); /* ... */ };
> struct B2 { B2(int); /* ... */ };
> struct D : B1, B2 {
>   D(int);
>   B1 b;
>   const int c;
> };
>
> D::D(int a) : B2(a+1), B1(a+2), c(a+3), b(a+4) { /* ... */ }
> D d(10);
> ```
>
> — end example ] [...]

thus direct-initializing the `mya` member:

```
b::b(int i2) : mya(i2) {
           //  ^^^^^^^- member initializer list
  j=2*i2;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

In the constructor of `b`, `mya=a(i2);` is assignment (but not initializtion). Before entering the body of constructor, `mya` is tried to be default-initialized but `a` doesn't have default constructor.

As you said you can add a default constructor for `a`, then `mya` would be default-initialized then get assigned inside the constructor of `b`.

The better way is to initialize `mya` in [member initializer list](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constructor).

```
b::b(int i2) : mya(i2) {
//           ^^^^^^^^^
  j=2*i2; // this could be moved to member initializer list too
}
```